# Change background of input field if start/end dates overlap that of another groups start/end dates

Tags: jquery, css

I cannot seem to get the fields to go a different colour when any of the dates in a group overlap that of another group's dates.  I used different colours so I could see which code was causing the colour change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//add more fields group
$(".addMore").click(function() {
  var fieldHTML = '<div class="eventGroup">' + $(".eventGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
  $('body').find('.eventGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
});
//remove fields group
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).parents(".eventGroup").remove();
});

// Add error class to empty fields
$('form').on('blur', 'input', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value === '') {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
  }
});

function convertDateToYYYYMMDD(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
  var newDate = [year, month, day].join('-');
  //alert('nd - ' + newDate);
  return newDate;
}

function isValidDate(dateString) {
  //alert('287 - isValidDate |' + dateString + '|');
  // Regular expression pattern for 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
  var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

  // Check if the date string matches the pattern
  if (!pattern.test(dateString)) {
    return false;
  }

  var parts = dateString.split('-');
  var year = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
  var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
  var day = parseInt(parts[2], 10); // Split the date string into year, month, and day components
  var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // Create a Date object from the components

  // Validate the Date object
  if (date.getFullYear() !== year || date.getMonth() + 1 !== month || date.getDate() !== day) {
    return false;
  }

  return true; // Date is valid
}

/*      keep above      */


/*      start of other code     */

var eventContainer = $('.form');

eventContainer.on('change', 'input[name="eventStart[]"], input[name="eventEnd[]"]', function() {
  validateDates();
});

function validateDates() {
  //alert('189 - validateDates');

  var currentDate = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(new Date());
  var isValid = true;

  eventContainer.find('.eventGroup').each(function() {

    var eventGroup = $(this);
    var eventStartInputs = eventGroup.find('input[name="eventStart[]"]');
    var eventEndInputs = eventGroup.find('input[name="eventEnd[]"]');
    eventStartInputs.css('background-color', '');
    eventEndInputs.css('background-color', '');

    eventStartInputs.each(function(index) {
      var eventStartInput = $(this);
      var eventEndInput = eventEndInputs.eq(index);
      var eventStartDate = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(eventStartInput.val());
      var eventEndDate = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(eventEndInput.val());
      //alert('207 - \r\n|' + eventStartDate + '| eventStartDate\r\n\r\n|' + eventEndDate + '| eventEndDate');

      //alert('210 - ch if valid date, if not, red' );
      if (!isValidDate(eventStartDate) || !isValidDate(eventEndDate)) {
        //alert('213 - date NOT ok, red');
        if (eventStartDate != 'NaN-NaN-NaN' && eventEndDate != 'NaN-NaN-NaN') {
          //alert('215 make green');
          eventStartInput.css('background-color', 'green');
          eventEndInput.css('background-color', 'green');
          isValid = false;
          return;
        }
      }

      var isFutureDate = eventStartDate > currentDate && eventEndDate > currentDate;
      var isStartBeforeEnd = eventStartDate <= eventEndDate;
      if (!isFutureDate || !isStartBeforeEnd) {
        eventStartInput.css('background-color', 'blue');
        eventEndInput.css('background-color', 'blue');
        isValid = false;
      }
    });
  });

  if (isValid) {
    eventContainer.find('.eventGroup').each(function() {

      var eventGroup = $(this);
      var eventStartInputs = eventGroup.find('input[name="eventStart[]"]');
      var eventEndInputs = eventGroup.find('input[name="eventEnd[]"]');
      eventStartInputs.css('background-color', '');
      eventEndInputs.css('background-color', '');
      var eventStartValues = eventStartInputs.map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get();

      var eventEndValues = eventEndInputs.map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get();

      eventContainer.find('.eventGroup').each(function() {
        var otherGroup = $(this);
        if (otherGroup[0] !== eventGroup[0]) {
          var otherEventStartInputs = otherGroup.find('input[name="eventStart[]"]');
          var otherEventEndInputs = otherGroup.find('input[name="eventEnd[]"]');

          otherEventStartInputs.css('background-color', '');
          otherEventEndInputs.css('background-color', '');

          var otherEventStartValues = otherEventStartInputs.map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
          }).get();

          var otherEventEndValues = otherEventEndInputs.map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
          }).get();

          var hasOverlap = checkDateOverlap(eventStartValues, eventEndValues, otherEventStartValues, otherEventEndValues);

          if (hasOverlap) {
            //alert('270 - mark ' + hasOverlap);
            eventStartInputs.css('background-color', 'red');
            eventEndInputs.css('background-color', 'red');
            otherEventStartInputs.css('background-color', 'red');
            otherEventEndInputs.css('background-color', 'red');
            isValid = false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

function checkDateOverlap(startDates1, endDates1, startDates2, endDates2) {
  //alert('do ol ch');
  for (var i = 0; i < startDates1.length; i++) {
    var startDate1 = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(startDates1[i]);
    var endDate1 = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(endDates1[i]);

    for (var j = 0; j < startDates2.length; j++) {
      var startDate2 = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(startDates2[j]);
      var endDate2 = convertDateToYYYYMMDD(endDates2[j]);
      //alert('299 overlap - \r\n|' + startDate1 + '| startDate1\r\n|' + endDate1 + '|' + ' endDate1\r\n|' + startDate2 + '|' + ' startDate2\r\n|' + endDate2 + '|' + ' endDate2');

      if (startDate1 != 'NaN-NaN-NaN' && endDate1 != 'NaN-NaN-NaN' && startDate2 != 'NaN-NaN-NaN' && endDate2 != 'NaN-NaN-NaN') {
        var isOverlap = !(startDate1 > endDate2 || endDate1 < startDate2);
        if (isOverlap) {
          //alert('306 - checkDateOverlap true');
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        //alert('310 - untouched date was not checked');
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form">
 <form method="post" action="edit.php">
    <div class="centerText">
       <div class="eventGroup">
          <input class="np"
             type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name"
             value="e1"><br>
          <input class="np"
             type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals"
             value="111"><br>
          <input class="se"
             type="date" name="eventStart[]"
             value="2023-08-16">
          <input class="se"
             type="date" name="eventEnd[]"
             value="2023-08-20">
          <div class="clearFloat"></div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
       </div>
       <div class="eventGroup">
          <input class="np"
             type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name"
             value="e2"><br>
          <input class="np"
             type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals"
             value="222"><br>
          <input class="se"
             type="date" name="eventStart[]"
             value="2023-08-23">
          <input class="se"
             type="date" name="eventEnd[]"
             value="2023-08-26">
          <div class="clearFloat"></div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
       </div>
       <div class="eventGroup">
          <input class="np"
             type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name"
             value="e3"><br>
          <input class="np"
             type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals"
             value="333"><br>
          <input class="se"
             type="date" name="eventStart[]"
             value="2023-08-28">
          <input class="se"
             type="date" name="eventEnd[]"
             value="2023-08-31">
          <div class="clearFloat"></div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
       </div>
       <div class="eventGroup" style="display: none;"></div>
       <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    </div>
    <br><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addMore">Add more</a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
 </form>
</div>
<!-- copy of input fields group -->
<div class="eventGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
   <input class="np" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name" value=""><br>
   <input class="np" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals" value=""><br>
   <input class="se" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="">
   <input class="se" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value=""><br>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a><br>
</div>
```

The HTML code as requested, to show what the page looks like. I don't know how much more I need to add to allow this HTML to be added to the post.

Comment: Just to add that the BG colour changes fine if the fields are 'changed' to empty. (not just because they are empty on load)

Comment: The `blur` code that changes "not on load" can be moved to its own function and called during startup as well as assigned as the `blur` handler.

Comment: One issue is that you reset the colours on the last iteration.   So it will only work (if it does at all, not looked completely) if the last one is different.   Please add some suitable HTML to the question so we can see how .eventGroup and eventStart/eventEnd relate to each other).

Comment: I am still learning JS and JQ.  The blur is only used at the moment to see if a field is changed to empty.  Would changing this fix or be a start to fixing the BG colour issue ?

Comment: ok, just reading the second reply..., it is very possible that I have something wrong with the logic part here.  or just going about it all wrong.

Comment: I've tried to add the html, but code is too long, I also first tried to edit the post, but message to add more info, what more can I add other than this is the HTML requested

Comment: Using html alerts it goes through each date to see if (onChange) a date is now empty, if so mark red, this works.  Then it checks each group of dates to make sure they do not overlap that of another group. (one one should have the same day in use)  this seems to work going by the html alerts.  But it is not changing the BG colour of the overlap dates.

Comment: Your loop does this: for each group, reset all the other groups, compare with other groups.   So on the last iteration, it... resets all the other groups.   `otherEventStartInputs.css('background-color', '');`

Comment: I have added the HTML to the original post.  On my end I changed all the css colouring so there is a different colour for all, error or not, its not doing what it should do.  It seems to me I have a major bug in my own logic and the code.  I'm gonna backup and try to redo this section again.

Comment: ah ok, i'll check the loop out first.

Comment: I suggest separating the logic from the UI.  ie find which inputs need to be changed, then change them all at the end, outside the loop.  Alternatively, reset all before the loop starts then don't reset inside the loop.

Comment: yes thats my plan, going to do each part one at a time. Thank you

Comment: You were right, it was my error in clearing all colours, I removed the lines that cleared them, eventStartInputs.css.., eventEndInputs.css.., otherEvent start and end.  all seems ok, apart from the field that was changed should also be red, but I'm sure I get that in a moment...  Thank you again for hightlighting where the error was in my code.

Comment: oh well, I that was it, turns out its not just that, i'm gonna redo,